# Ubuntu Updates requires more security

Tags: updates

When I type "sudo apt-get update"
I see HTTP protocol is used to fetch the updates .
Why not HTTPS is used for more secure communication ?

Comment: There is no need to encrypt, because everything is signed.

Comment: You might like to read this article: [Why does APT not use HTTPS?](https://whydoesaptnotusehttps.com/)

Comment: why "archive.ubuntu.com" doesn't  work with "https" ?